# issues when using the `linalg` package from `Cupy`

Tags: python, cupy

I installed the latest version of`cupy`. This is part of what's returned when I run `conda list`:

```
colorlog                  6.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              37.0.1          py310h9ce1e76_0
cudatoolkit               11.7.0              hd8887f6_10    nvidia
cupy-cuda11x              11.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
cvxpy                     1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

I have these line somewhere in my script:

```
import numpy as np

try:
    import cupy as xp
except ImportError:
    import numpy as xp

from nda.optimizers.utils import eps
from nda import log

norm = xp.linalg.norm


def relative_error(w, w_0):
    return norm(w - w_0) / norm(w_0)
... ...
```

however, when I run the code the following error is returned:

```
$ python logistic_regression.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Randy666/Documents/projects/ICON_lab/Network-Distributed-Algorithm/experiments/convex/logistic_regression.py", line 6, in <module>
    from nda.problems import LogisticRegression
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Randy666/Documents/projects/ICON_lab/Network-Distributed-Algorithm/nda/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from nda import optimizers
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Randy666/Documents/projects/ICON_lab/Network-Distributed-Algorithm/nda/optimizers/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from nda.optimizers.optimizer import Optimizer
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Randy666/Documents/projects/ICON_lab/Network-Distributed-Algorithm/nda/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 13, in <module>
    norm = xp.linalg.norm
AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'linalg'
```

**Edit: I solved the `no attribute` error. However, the following happened:**

```
In [1]: import cupy;from cupy import linalg

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x = np.array([1,2,3])

In [4]: linalg.norm(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CUDARuntimeError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 linalg.norm(x)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/Randy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cupy/linalg/_norms.py:62, in norm(x, ord, axis, keepdims)
     60     ret = cupy.sqrt(s.sum())
     61 else:
---> 62     ret = cupy.sqrt((x * x).sum())
     63 if keepdims:
     64     ret = ret.reshape((1,) * ndim)

File cupy/_core/_kernel.pyx:1221, in cupy._core._kernel.ufunc.__call__()

File cupy/cuda/device.pyx:48, in cupy.cuda.device.get_device_id()

File cupy_backends/cuda/api/runtime.pyx:178, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.runtime.getDevice()

File cupy_backends/cuda/api/runtime.pyx:143, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.runtime.check_status()

CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorNoDevice: no CUDA-capable device is detected

In [5]:
```

I have the paths set up as the following:

```
(Randy) randy233@Randy-Desktop:~$ echo $CUDA_PATH
/home/randy233/anaconda3/envs/Randy

(Randy) randy233@Randy-Desktop:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH$
/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib$
```

How should I resolve the `CUDARuntimeError` ?

Comment: What does `import cupy; dir(cupy)` print?

Comment: these are returned:
`In [1]: import cupy; dir(cupy)
Out[1]:
['__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__']`

Comment: Is the `cupy` module even supposed to have `linalg`? If yes, please provide a link to documentation that says so.

Comment: there is `linalg` in fact. Please see my edited post